# A dataset for Google Books

Tags: data-request, books

Do you know if there is any (open) database for Google Books titles or texts? It could be used for text analysis and statistics.

Answer (score 4):

Google Books publishes an API. https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/getting_started

Of course one of the prohibitions in their ToS (https://developers.google.com/terms/) is "you will not...Scrape, build databases or otherwise create permanent copies of such content" so if anyone built an open database from this data, which I think is what you're asking for, it may be in violation of the ToS.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Web Services provide several open dataset for their clients including mathematics, economics, biology, astronomy etc. **One of them is Google Books Ngrams.** It's not exactly titles dataset but it is a 2.2 TB with Ngrams.

N-grams are fixed size tuples of items. In this case the items are words extracted from the Google Books corpus. The n specifies the number of elements in the tuple, so a 5-gram contains five words or characters.

```
The yellow dog played fetch.
```

Would produce the following 2-grams:

["The", "yellow"] 
["yellow", 'dog"] 
["dog", "played"] 
["played", "fetch"] 
["fetch", "."]

For more details check this [link](http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/Encyclopedic/8172056142375670)

Answer (score 1):

[Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/) hosts public domain books and texts and offers a [bulk download](https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Information_About_Robot_Access_to_our_Pages#How_To_Get_All_Ebook_Files).

There is also a [python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Gutenberg) to download and clean up texts.

---

You could also do a bulk download of [WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Main_Page) - see these links for more details

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwikibooks/20160203/